# Generate adjacency list from grid of colors

Tags: java, graph

I can't find anything similiar to this online. I have a grid with multiple colors, denoted by 0 to N. So for example, the graph could look like this:

```
0 0 1 1 1 2 2
0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 3 3 3 4 4
1 1 3 4 4 4 4
```

I want to represent this in an adjacency list that shows which ones are connected. This seems very simple and common, but I can't find a solution online.

So the result list would look like:

```
0: 1
1: 0, 2, 3, 4
2: 1
3: 1, 4
4: 3, 1
```

My idea would be to go through the whole grid from the top left to the bottom right, checking if north, south, east, west has different color, then adding edge to adjacency list. I don't know if this is a good algorithm (I expected something with floodfill, but I don't think I need it). I am hoping the experts here can give me a better algorithm or confirm that this algorithm is works.

Comment: well, it's O(n) your program... so I would say there is not better way to do it, because you have to check every element, not matter what

Comment: Note that you can probably avoid checking all four directions.  Two is enough, if you process both direction adjacency adds at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'algorithm' needs some more details, but seems to be essentially correct.

For details of a similar problem see
( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Hills ) which looks at height in an orthogonal grid ( instead of colour. )

You can take a look at the C++ code  that reads the grid and creates the adjacency matrix [starting here](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/2cc69596634588723136435cdda8b9715f161c64/src/cPathFinderReader.cpp#L278) I expect you can port this to java and adjust for your particular needs.

Comment: From [answer] -- _"Links to external resources are encouraged [...]. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."_

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to iterate from top left to bottom right. For a given cell, you check two neighboring cells: the one on the right, and the one below. Lets assume the top left of your grid has coordinates (0,0) and bottom right has coordinates (m,n). Then when you are at cell (i,j), you check the neighbors: (i+1,j) and (i,j+1). Maintain a hashmap to track your adjacency list. Let c_i,j be the color of cell (i,j). Every iteration you would add:
`adjacencyMap.get(c_i,j).add(c_i,j+1)` and `colorMap.get(c_i,j+1).add(c_i,j)`
when you are at (i,j) and you check (i+1,j). Similar for (i,j) and (i,j+1).

Note: I wasn't sure whether you also consider neighbors on the diagonal. If this is the case, you would also check (i,j) and (i+1,j+1).